# node edges (arrows) positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

I produce a node/ edge plot with `tikz` using the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    % nodes
    \node (A)  at (3.5, 5) {ABC};
    \node (B)   at (3.5, 4) {some slightly longer text in here};
    \node (C)  at (1, 3) {some other thext here};
    \node (D)  at (6, 3) {name of node displayed here};
    \node (E) at (9.5, 2) {name of another node about here};
    \node (F)  at (4, 2.5) {next node's titletext};
    \node (G) at (4, 1) {final node displayed here};

    % arrows
    \draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}]
    (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (C) edge (F)
                              (C) edge (G)
                 (B) edge (D) (D) edge (E) (E) edge (G);        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the arrows aren't placed properly. I would like to roughly keep the configuration of the nodes and have some arrows start at the bottom of the node (e.g. bottom middle of node (A)) or go straight to the bottom (e.g. (from (C) to (G)) rather than first horizontally and then vertically. The picture below shows in black the output of above code; in red the lines I would roughly like to get (as arrows, of course), although I am not very set on these exact lines if it makes the code less complicated and more robust.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions for how to accomplish this and modify the `edge` starting points and paths.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Does this meet the requirement--the dash line can be replaced with arrows

### The MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    % nodes
    \node (A)  at (3.5, 5) {ABC};
    \node (B)   at (3.5, 4) {some slightly longer text in here};
    \node (C)  at (1, 3) {some other thext here};
    \node (D)  at (6, 3) {name of node displayed here};
    \node (E) at (9.5, 2) {name of another node about here};
    \node (F)  at (4, 2.5) {next node's titletext};
    \node (G) at (4, 1) {final node displayed here};

    % arrows
    % \draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}]
    % (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (C) edge (F)
    %                           (C) edge (G)
    %              (B) edge (D) (D) edge (E) (E) edge (G);  
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (B) -- (C);
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (C) -- (F);
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (C) -- (G);
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (B) -- (D);
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (D) -- (E);
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (E) -- (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

for the arrows(red)

for the node (D) which is too close to node (C) `\xshift` added 4.5

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    % nodes
    \node (A)  at (3.5, 5) {ABC};
    \node (B)   at (3.5, 4) {some slightly longer text in here};
    \node (C)  at (1, 3) {some other thext here};
    \node (D)  at (6, 3) {name of node displayed here};
    \node (E) at (9.5, 2) {name of another node about here};
    \node (F)  at (4.5, 2) {next node's titletext};
    \node (G) at (4, 1) {final node displayed here};

    % arrows
    % \draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}]
    % (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (C) edge (F)
    %                           (C) edge (G)
    %              (B) edge (D) (D) edge (E) (E) edge (G);  
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (B) -- (C);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (C) -- (F);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (C) -- (G);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (B) -- (D);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (D) -- (E);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (E) -- (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

for `Manhattan style` mixed with `regular style`

node H defined new for a new arrow origin point

node D shifted right to create space for the arrow coming down from node H

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    % nodes
    \node (A)  at (3.5, 5) {ABC};
    \node (B)   at (3.5, 4) {some slightly longer text in here};
    \node (C)  at (1, 3) {some other thext here};
    \node (D)  at (7, 3) {name of node displayed here};
    \node (E) at (9.5, 2) {name of another node about here};
    \node (F)  at (4.5, 2) {next node's titletext};
    \node (G) at (4, 1) {final node displayed here};
    \node (H) at (3.6,4) {};
    % \node (J) at (3.6,4) {};
    % arrows
    % \draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}]
    % (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (C) edge (F)
    %                           (C) edge (G)
    %              (B) edge (D) (D) edge (E) (E) edge (G);  
    \draw [thick,dash dot, red] (A) -- (B);
    \draw  (B) |- (C);
    \draw [ red] (C) |- (F);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (C) |- (G);
    \draw [->,thick, red] (H) |- (D);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (D) -- (E);
    \draw [->,thick,dash dot, red] (E) -- (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is already much better than the original plot! :) Is there any way to not draw direct lines but lines in 'Manhattan distance' style? :)

Comment: of course--  `\draw (A) -| (B);` will give you the desired result-- u can also experiment with `|-`---- the `-` represents horizontal draw and `|` represents vertical line

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more alternatives:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
        % nodes
        \node (A)  at (3.5, 5) {ABC};
        \node (B)[below of=A]{some slightly longer text in here};
        \node (C)[below left=  and -1cm of B]{some other thext here};
        \node (D)[below right= and -2cm of B]{name of node displayed here};
        \node (E)[below right= and -2cm of D] {name of another node about here};
        \node (F)[below =2cm of B]{next node's titletext};
        \node (G)[below=of F]{final node displayed here};

        % arrows
        \draw[->](A)--(B);
        \draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}](B) edge (C)
                                               (B) edge (D)
                                               (D) edge (E);
        \draw[->, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}](C) edge (F)
                                               (C) edge (G)
                                               (E) edge (G) ;        
    \end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    % nodes
    \node (A)  at (3.5, 5) {ABC};
    \node (B)[below of=A]{some slightly longer text in here};
    \node (C)[below left=  and -1cm of B]{some other thext here};
    \node (C1)[right = -1.5cm of C]{\phantom{l}};
    \node (D)[below right= and -2cm of B]{name of node displayed here};
    \node (E)[below right= and -2cm of D] {name of another node about here};
    \node (F)[below =2cm of B]{next node's titletext};
    \node (G)[below=of F]{final node displayed here};

    % arrows
    \draw[->](A)--(B);
    \draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}](B) edge (C)
                                           (B) edge (D)
                                           (D) edge (E);
    \draw[->, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}](C1) edge (F)
                                           (C) edge (G)
                                           (E) edge (G) ;        
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    % nodes
    \node (A)  at (3.5, 5) {ABC};
    \node (B)[below of=A]{some slightly longer text in here};
    \node (Cb)[below= of B.south west]{\phantom{l}};
    \node (C)[below left=  and -1cm of B]{some other thext here};
    \node (C1)[right = -1.5cm of C]{\phantom{l}};
    \node (Cd)[below= of B.south east]{\phantom{l}};
    \node (D)[below right= and -2cm of B]{name of node displayed here};
    \node (De)[below= of D.south east]{\phantom{l}};
    \node (E)[below right= and -2cm of D] {name of another node about here};
    \node (F)[below =2cm of B]{next node's titletext};
    \node (G)[below=of F]{final node displayed here};

    % arrows
    \draw[->](A)--(B);
    \draw[->](B.south west) -- (Cb);
    \draw[->](B.south east) -- (Cd);
    \draw[->](D.south east) -- (De);
    \draw[->, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}](C1) edge (F)
                                           (C) edge (G)
                                           (E) edge (G) ;        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```